# Por que o item do meu Array não é alterado no foreach?

Tags: java

Na chamada do método:

```
 AlunoPrivado aluno = new AlunoPrivado();
 aluno.addCursos("Portugues", "matemática", "história", "física");
 boolean result = aluno.changeCurso("Portugues", "ciências");
```

Método implementado:

```
public boolean changeCurso(String cursoModificar, String cursoNovo) {
    for(String curso : cursos) {
        if (curso.equals(cursoModificar) ) {
            curso = cursoNovo;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

O método `changeCurso()` retorna `true` mas, no *Array*, o curso não é alterado.

Comment: Você trocou o `==` por `Equals()`? Aí deu certo? Como eu uso mais C#, eu costumo esquecer desse detalhe. Me confirma isto e eu respondo.

Comment: Troquei sim, mas não funfa ainda...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não é possível repor o conteúdo de uma posição de um Array ou de uma colecção através do *foreach*. Tem de usar o *for* clássico para isso.

O *Array*, de uma forma simplista, é guardado em memória da seguinte forma:

- Cada um dos itens(valores) atribuídos ao *Array* são guardados em posições de memória.

  ```
  Endereço    Valor
   #00010  "Portugues"
   #00011  "matemática"
   #00013  "história", 
   #00014  "física"
  ```
- A cada posição do *Array* é atribuída uma posição de memória que guarda, não o valor propriamente dito, mas o endereço onde o respectivo valor foi guardado.

  ```
  Endereço    Valor  indice
   #00001     #00010   [0]
   #00002     #00011   [1]
   #00003     #00012   [2]
   #00004     #00013   [3]
  ```

O que a variável do *foreach* `curso` recebe é a referência(endereço) onde está guardado o valor correspondente ao índice em questão e não o endereço da posição do *Array*

Quando a condição `curso.equals(cursoModificar)` é verdadeira, a variável `curso` tem como valor(referencia) o endereço **#00010**.

A variável `cursoNovo` também referencia uma posição de memória, aquela que lhe foi atribuída quando o método foi chamado, por ex.: **#00030**.

Quando é executada a linha `curso = cursoNovo;`, `curso` passa a referenciar o endereço **#00030**, aquele onde está a string "ciências", no entanto nada foi alterado no *Array*. A posição `[0]`, que está guardada no endereço **#00001**, continua a referenciar o endereço **#00010**, que continua a guardar a *String* "Portugues".

Confuso? Talvez não, se conseguir pensar em endereços em vez de valores.

<sub>Nota: Os valores dos endereços são apenas indicativos.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Você está modificando o valor da variável local 'curso', apenas isso, por isso não está funcionando.

Você teria que modificar o valor do array.

Tipo assim

```
for ( int i = 0; i < cursos.length; i++ )
{
    if ( cursos[i] == cursoModificar )
    {
        cursos[i] = cursoNovo;
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Eu fiz esse exemplo tendo em mente que 'cursos' é uma array, caso seja uma lista basta modificar os métodos.

Comment: Hummm. Mas e com um for each ficaria como esse método?

Comment: Da uma lida na resposta do seu @ramaral

Answer (score 1):

Se cursos for um ArrayList tente assim:

```
public boolean changeCurso(String cursoModificar, String cursoNovo) {
    for(String curso : cursos) {
        if (curso.equals(cursoModificar)) {
            int index = aluno.cursos.indexOf(curso);
            aluno.cursos.remove(index);
            aluno.cursos.add(index,cursoNovo);
            return true;
    }
}
    return false; }
```

Comment: Não é um ArrayList.