# Usando Array.Foreach para modificar a coleção

Tags: c#, .net, array, string, linq

Eu quero remover espaços do início e fim da string (`Trim`) em todas posições do *array*, mas nenhuma das formas abaixo funcionaram.
O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
var optionArray = new string[] { "in the jungle ", " the mighty jungle", " the lion sleeps tonight " };

Array.ForEach(optionArray, x => x.Trim()); // nada acontece
Array.ForEach(optionArray, x => x = x.Trim()); // nada acontece
optionArray = Array.ForEach(optionArray, x => x = x.Trim()); // Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string[]'

var optionList = optionArray.ToList();

optionList.ForEach(x => x.Trim()); // nada acontece
optionList.ForEach(x => x = x.Trim()); // nada acontece
optionList = optionList.ForEach(x => x = x.Trim()); // Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
```

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/112092/2541) para perceber porque o *ForEach* não funciona quando se pretende alterar um valor da lista. Ela se refere a Java mas o mesmo se aplica ao C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Daniel complementando a resposta do Maniero, o [Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/) em 2009 escreveu um bom artigo em seu `blog`, nele ele explica os malefícios de se usar o `List<T>.ForEach` no lugar do `foreach`. Você pode ler o artigo na integra no seguinte link.: [“foreach” vs “ForEach”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/)

Um outro argumento, seria que os próprios arquitetos da Micrsoft decidiram não incluir um método `ForEach` no Linq, você pode ler a respeito do assunto em.: [Why no ForEach method on IEnumerable interfaces](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2011/09/21/why-no-foreach-method-on-ienumerable-interfaces/)

mas em resumo, você não deve usar o `List<T>.ForEach`, por que este viola os princípios da programação funcional, podendo causar alguns efeitos colaterais. além de que, o `List<T>.ForEach` é menos legível e isto pode implicar em uma manutenção mais difícil (tente *debuggar* uma iteração dentro de um `List<T>.ForEach`).

Ainda assim, este um cenário onde este tipo de implementação pode vir a ser útil, paralelismo... e mesmo assim existe todo um `Namespace` para tratar disto.: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var lista = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();
Parallel.ForEach(lista, (item, state, indice) => {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("indice: {0}, value: {1}", indice, item));
});
```

mas a implementação ainda vai sofrer do mesmo problema, você não vai conseguir modificar a lista, neste caso você precisar fazer uso do `Parallel.For` e acessar o elemento pelo índice.:

```
var lista = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();
Parallel.For(0, lista.Count, (indice, state) => {
    lista[indice] *= 2;
});

foreach(var item in lista) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("value: {0}", item));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/ModifyStructure.cs).

E por fim, um bom motivo para não usar o `.Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray()`, você não está modificando os valores do *array*. Você está criando um novo *array* com os novos valores, neste ponto você terá dois *arrays* em memoria, então estará apenas desperdiçando memoria, ciclos da CPU e forçado que o *garbage collector* seja chamado mais vezes.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar o [`Select()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) do LINQ, mas precisa criar um novo *array*:

```
var newArray = optionArray.Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
```

A não ser que queira fazer "manual" (provavelmente o que eu faria):

```
for (var i = 0; i < optionArray.Length; i++) {
    optionArray[i] = optionArray[i].Trim();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KdDItS). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WsK5XN). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/Change.cs).

Comment: Não é possível alterar coleção com `ForEach`? Parece que isso é feito em um exemplo do [DotNetPearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-foreach#d). Por que você faria da maneira "manual"?

Comment: Daniel, ele não está alterando o valor dos itens da coleção, está simplesmente "logando no console" os valores no momento em que percorre cada item. Funcionaria para você caso você quisesse apenas logar este valor, como por exemplo:
optionList.ForEach(x => { Console.WriteLine(x.Trim()) });
Isso logaria os valores sem espaço, mas não modificaria o array.

Comment: Não é possível, o elemento não é passado por referência, então não é alterado no *array*. Até poderia, mas teria que criar outro *array* também. Se quiser mesmo usar um método e *lambda* prefira usar o LINQ, é mais moderno e faz o que quer. Eu iria até de `foreach` mesmo.