# C# Como alterar valor dentro do Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, lista, foreach, stack, heap

Estou realizando um processamento dentro de um array de strings (linhas de um arquivo .txt).

Por motivos de performance, estou usando o `Parallel.ForEach`, mas surgiu a necessidade de alterar os valores de algumas linhas que não foram processadas.

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível alterar o valor de um elemento da lista dentro do foreach

Segue código

```
List<string> linhas = new List<string>();

// imaginem essas linhas com varios valores

Parallels.Foreach(linhas, (linha) => {

    //algum processamento

    linha = "não processado"; //como resolver isso


});
```

Meus testes provaram que não funciona, mas eu gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de fazer isso.

Comment: `Parallels.Foreach` terá um impacto negativo na performance em relação ao `foreach` clássico. Além disso, você não pode alterar a coleção que está iterando dentro do bloco For Each.

Comment: @CypherPotato "terá um impacto negativo na performance" como assim? Haverá situações em que isso é verdade mas não em todas.

Comment: Bom, independente disso, você ainda não poderá alterar qualquer elemento da coleção que está iterando dentro do bloco For Each. O que você pode fazer, é usar o `Parallels.For` e alterar por índice na coleção do objeto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possível alterar pela [mesma razão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/112092/2541) que não é possível no foreach "normal".

Em alternativa use [Parallel.For](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netframework-4.8).